# Can't make node.js ubuntu 13.10

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, g++, makefile

I'm trying to install node.js, so I've cloned the repo and `./configure` it. However, when I run make I get this ridiculous infinite loop of errors:

```
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/nodejs/node/out'
  g++ '-DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2=1' '-DV8_TARGET_ARCH_X64' '-DENABLE_DEBUGGER_SUPPORT' -I../deps/v8/src  -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -O3 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-tree-vrp -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -O3 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -MMD -MF /home/ubuntu/nodejs/node/out/Release/.deps//home/ubuntu/nodejs/node/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base.x64/deps/v8/src/runtime.o.d.raw  -c -o /home/ubuntu/nodejs/node/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base.x64/deps/v8/src/runtime.o ../deps/v8/src/runtime.cc
In file included from ../deps/v8/src/v8.h:52:0,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/runtime.cc:31:
../deps/v8/src/../include/v8.h: In member function ‘void v8::ReturnValue<T>::Set(uint32_t)’:
../deps/v8/src/../include/v8.h:5816:31: warning: typedef ‘I’ locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
   typedef internal::Internals I;
                               ^
In file included from ../deps/v8/src/v8globals.h:32:0,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/v8.h:53,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/runtime.cc:31:
../deps/v8/src/v8utils.h: In function ‘void v8::internal::CopyWords(T*, const T*, size_t)’:
../deps/v8/src/checks.h:271:22: warning: typedef ‘__StaticAssertTypedef__131’ locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
     SEMI_STATIC_JOIN(__StaticAssertTypedef__, __LINE__)
                      ^
../deps/v8/src/checks.h:261:39: note: in definition of macro ‘SEMI_STATIC_JOIN_HELPER’
 #define SEMI_STATIC_JOIN_HELPER(a, b) a##b
                                       ^
../deps/v8/src/checks.h:271:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘SEMI_STATIC_JOIN’
     SEMI_STATIC_JOIN(__StaticAssertTypedef__, __LINE__)
     ^
../deps/v8/src/checks.h:319:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘STATIC_CHECK’
 #define STATIC_ASSERT(test)  STATIC_CHECK(test)
```

This seems to be a bug but I have `g++4.8.1` `gcc-4.8.1` which are the latest versions that I know of. Please let me know how I can fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Its better to install by "sudo apt-get install nodejs 
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node "

Comment: Did your configure complain in any way about missing libraries? Even warnings? If you could post configure's log that would be nice (maybe thru pastebin, and not directly here).

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? What you posted are just warnings as far as I can tell, not errors.

Comment: It kept repeating the same warnings and never actually compiled any code. Anyway I just added a repository and apt-get installed it. What a pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had problems with g++ 4.8 compiling v8 (which Node uses), and a bunch of other stuff, so I use 4.7. First install g++-4.7 using `apt-get` (which I trust you know how to do), and then:

```
CXX=g++-4.7 make [... etc...]
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an easier way than bringing old g++, as mentioned in V8 bug report discussion:
http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2149

You could set additional flag for g++ before using make:

```
export CXX="g++ -Wno-unused-local-typedefs"
```

Comment: Just tried building node from src on 14.04 server, and this fixed it for me. Thanks